# How to request for "like" for the function "populate"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to retrieve with a search field the channels according to the user's first name.

```js
    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        _profile: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Profile',
            require: true,
            unique: true
        }
    })
    
    
    const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        }
    })
    
    
    const ChannelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        _user: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        }
    })
    
    
    const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
    const Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema)
    const Channel = mongoose.model('Channel', ChannelSchema)
```

I used to `populate` function to retrieve the data from the joins

```
let ChannelSearch = await Channel
    .find()
    .populate({
        path: '_user',
        select:'-password',
        populate: {
            path: '_profile'
        }
    })
```

but where I block is how to retrieve the channels based on the user's first name

I can't seem to find how it is possible to make a `like` request through the `populate` function

Thank you in advance for your help !! =)

Answer (score 0):

you can your regex to find your data.

```js
let ChannelSearch = await Channel
    .find({firstname: /regex/})
    .populate({
        path: '_user',
        select:'-password',
        populate: {
            path: '_profile'
        }
    })
```

or use $regex in yout mongo query.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: I have tried several things
```.find({firstname: `/${action.data.search}/`})```
```.find({firstname: {$regex: `/${action.data.search}/`}})```
```.find({firstname: {$regex: `.*${action.data.search}.*`}})```
```.find({'_user._profile.firstname': {$regex: `.*${action.data.search}.*`}})```...
But it reminds me of an empty board

Comment: did you check your regex?

Comment: I found this on the doc or on Google searches

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, in the mongoose documentation it is put this:

> In general, there is no way to make populate() filter stories based on properties of the story's author. For example, the below query won't return any results, even though author is populated.

```js
const story = await Story.
  findOne({ 'author.name': 'Ian Fleming' }).
  populate('author').
  exec();
story; // null
```

> If you want to filter stories by their author's name, you should use [denormalization](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).